# By using CRM 2011 online, I want to E-mail INVOICE automatically with Product Description(line items) in ,to My Customers

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

My Organization wants to Email (automatically means system itself generate the invoice mail) Invoices to their Customers 25th of every Month with the number of products(LINE ITEMS Means Invoice products) in The INVOICE. For Having Line items in the invoive form I've made some customization and add "grid" Which now shows the line items information means you get information that how many products this invoice actually is..

For this I've made an e-mail tempelete For the Entity invoice .But Problem is that the grids fields are not there in the the tempelete "Insert\delete" option .

I research alot and made all possible attempts To mail(AUTOMATICALLY) the invoice with all the line items in it

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that with a template. I think this needs to be done using a workflow anyway, so your template should be for building the general body of the mail, and after your workflow has generated the eMail activity from the template, it needs to run a Custom Workflow Activity that queries the database for the line items and adds the information to the eMail text.

Comment: If it is _really_ urgent, I suggest contracting support or an external knowledgeable expert.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to easily accomplish what you wish to do.  You can't create custom workflow activities in crm online so your only real option is to create some type of external program that does the work.  Templates will only handle part of the problem and not the invoice line items at all.